# Could not kill the current process in android

Tags: android

I have an application in which I need to kill the application after it asks some confirmation from the user. I am using the following code snippet.

```
    while(tts.isSpeaking());

tts.speak("Quitting application",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    while(tts.isSpeaking());
    tts.shutdown();
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

The tts engine is saying "quitting application". And screen goes blank for some time. Then after that the application is restarting. I am not getting where I am going wrong.

I have tried the `System.exit(0)` as well. Still same thing happening. Show me the right way. I also have some problems with using tts. I can't synchronize the speaking and many events during application run. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: dude if my answer is helpful to u then u can vote up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dude try `finish()` it will finish activity and specify brackets . dont use 
           `int pid =       android.os.Process.myPid();
     android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);` inside while and to kill entire application use
**REMEMBER**
             `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);`
             `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
             `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);`
              `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: yes finish() is working fine thanks man. but sometime back in another application , it did not work. so i have used the kill process method. i am not getting why the approaches works different in different applications.

Comment: hey dude , can u please tell me what should i do to know about the usage of tts to synchronize various events in my application .it is irritating me,i am not getting how to synchronize the events and the tts.

Comment: what is the new code is all about, i am not even getting it a bit. pleas explain me. and as well the diff between finish and kill

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have {} around the while loop? eg

```
    while(tts.isSpeaking()) {
    tts.shutdown();
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
    }
```

Comment: how can ur approach is correct yaar, while tts is still speaking, i should wait, thats why i have used a single line. after u shutdown the tts engine and then kill the current process...

Comment: Off topic. Having a `while` in a tight loop is often a bad idea. You should consider either a `Thread.yield()` or `Thread.sleep()` to prevent that thread hogging the system resources.